# How to deal with precision loss in vtk for reading/writing ply?

Tags: c++, vtk, paraview

I'm trying to parse binary mesh data (ply) into a text `ply` and I need to maintain a 3-decimal precision. The code below produces a valid ply file. The data I'm dealing with has up to 10 digits. The problem is: the output coordinates are snapped to some grid which is maybe due to some precision loss.

```
# Expected X, Y, Z values
587028.529 1052864.229 307.586
587026.316 1052869.535 306.553

# Output X, Y, Z values
587028.500 1052864.250 307.586
587026.312 1052869.500 306.553

Version: vtk-devel-8.2.0-23 (Fedora 33)
```

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vtkPLYReader.h>
#include <vtkPLYWriter.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkTriangleFilter.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "  Filename(.ply)" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  std::string inputFilename = argv[1];
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName( inputFilename.c_str() );
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> mesh;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter> triangles = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter>::New();
  triangles->SetInputConnection( reader->GetOutputPort() );
  triangles->Update();
  mesh = triangles->GetOutput();
  std::ofstream ply;
  ply.open( "new.ply" );
  ply << "ply\n"
      << "format ascii 1.0\n"
      << "comment TMC generated PLY File\n"
      << "element vertex " << mesh->GetNumberOfPoints() << "\n"
      << "property double x\n"
      << "property double y\n"
      << "property double z\n"
      << "element face " << mesh->GetNumberOfCells() << "\n"
      << "property list uchar int vertex_indices\n"
      << "end_header\n";
  vtkIdType i;
  for( i = 0; i < mesh->GetNumberOfPoints(); i++ )
  {
    double p[3];
    std::stringstream x, y, z;
    mesh->GetPoint( i, p );
    x << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 ) << p[0];
    y << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 ) << p[1];
    z << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 ) << p[2];
    ply << x.str() << " " << y.str() << " " << z.str() << "\n";
  }
  vtkCell* face;
  for( i = 0; i < mesh->GetNumberOfCells(); i++ )
  {
    face = mesh->GetCell( i );
    ply << face->GetNumberOfPoints();
    for( int j = 0; j < face->GetNumberOfPoints(); j++ )
      ply << " " << face->GetPointId( j );
    ply << "\n";
  }
  ply.close();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How to avoid precision loss in VTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggest in my latest comment, if you use the original PLY file library, you can be sure that you won't lose any precision.  Apparently somewhere internally VTK is casting your doubles to floats.  The original PLY code is pretty simple, so you can figure out what it does and be sure that it won't do that cast.

Here's a link to the PLY file C library:
https://www.cc.gatech.edu/projects/large_models/ply.html

Comment: I am able to output with the desired precision. The problem is that reading via VTK, the double values seem to become float. That is why the values for X and Y are modified.

Comment: For example, I am expecting a value of `587026.316` but the output is `587026.312`.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I misunderstood your question.  My suggestion would be to get the original ply file C code to do the reading/writing.  Clearly they're casting your doubles to floats somewhere internally, so its unlikely that you can undo that. https://www.cc.gatech.edu/projects/large_models/ply.html